# How to fadein prepend li with background color and border color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want fadein effect with backgroundcolor and border.

```
$('ul#listticker').prepend($('<li>../li>')
                  .fadeIn(1000)
                  .animate({
                        backgroundColor:'#fff8cc',
                        borderTopColor:"#ff0000",
                        borderBottomColor:'#ff0000',
                        borderLeftColor:'#ff0000',
                        borderRightColor:'#ff0000'
                        },"slow")
                    );
```

I tried above code but it only work background color.And also i need fadeout with backgroundcolor and border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are, just looks like you had to define a border to start in your css

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/xRYJX/